# Haskell lenses: how to make view play nicely with traverse?

Tags: haskell, lenses, traversable

I am trying to learn about lenses by implementing it in Haskell. I have implemented the `view` combinator as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable

type Lens s a = Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s

view :: Lens s a -> s -> a
view lens = getConst . lens Const
```

However when I try to use it in conjunction with `traverse` I get the following error message:

```
Prelude> :load Lens.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Lens.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :t view traverse

<interactive>:1:6:
    Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of ‘traverse’
    from the context (Traversable t)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Traversable t => t a -> a
      at Top level
    or from (Functor f)
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 Functor f => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
      at <interactive>:1:1-13
    Possible fix:
      add (Applicative f) to the context of
        a type expected by the context:
          Functor f => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
        or the inferred type of it :: Traversable t => t a -> a
    In the first argument of ‘view’, namely ‘traverse’
    In the expression: view traverse
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand this error message. Please explain what it means and how I may fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the other answers already explain, the issue is that `view` expects something that works for any `Functor f`, but `traverse` only works if `f` is also `Applicative` (and there are functors which are not applicative).

In `lens`, the problem is solved by making the type of `view` not take a `Rank2` argument (in fact, most functions in lens don't use the Lens type synonym, they always use something weaker). For your function, observe that `view` only ever uses `f ~ Const`. This is why you can change the type signature to:

```
view :: ((a -> Const a a) -> s -> Const a s) -> s -> a
```

The implementation can stay the same, but now `view` also works on `traverse`:

```
view traverse :: (Traversable t, Monoid a) => t a -> a
```

Note the extra `Monoid` constraint. This constraint appears because if you set `f ~ Const a` in `traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)`, you need an instance `Applicative (Const a)`. That instance has a `Monoid` constraint on `a` though. And this also makes sense, because the traversable might be empty or contain more than one element, so you need `mempty` and `mappend`.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much for a smart solution to the problem. I do have one question though: wouldn't the type signature of `view` become `((a -> Const a a) -> s -> Const a s) -> s -> a`?

Answer (score 3):

`traverse` has this type:

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (x -> f y) -> t x -> f (t y)
```

If we make the free variable `f` in the type definition of `Lens` explicit, its definition is actually

```
type Lens s a = forall f . Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

So `view` wants a function that can operate on *any* `Functor`, whereas `traverse` can only operate on an `Applicative`.

You can fix the error simply by changing `Functor` into `Applicative` in the definition of `Lens`, but I'm not sure if that's exactly what you would want to achieve here.

Comment: Changing `Functor` to `Applicative` here will give you a `Traversal`, won't it? I guess this gives some intuition for where the name "Traversal" comes from.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr - According to your definition of `Lens`, a `traverse` cannot be a `Lens` because `traverse` doesn't work for all `Functor`s.

---

Let's take a look at your types:

```
λ :set -XRankNTypes 
λ :m +Control.Applicative Data.Traversable 
λ type Lens s a = Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
λ :t traverse
traverse
  :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Now at this point we can see that `traverse` is, in one way, slightly more general than our `Lens` type - it can take a function
from `a -> f b` where our lens can only take functions from `a -> f a`.

Restricting it to that case is no problem, so we can say

```
λ :t traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
  :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
```

So now it's obvious that if `traverse` is to be a `Lens`, it must be a `Lens (t a) a`, since that's the only way to make the type variables line up.

So let's try that out.

```
λ :t traverse :: Lens (t a) a

<interactive>:1:1:
    Could not deduce (Traversable t1) arising from a use of `traverse'
    from the context (Functor f)
      bound by the inferred type of
               it :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
      at Top level
    or from (Functor f1)
      bound by an expression type signature:
                 Functor f1 => (a1 -> f1 a1) -> t1 a1 -> f1 (t1 a1)
      at <interactive>:1:1-24
    Possible fix:
      add (Traversable t1) to the context of
        an expression type signature:
          Functor f1 => (a1 -> f1 a1) -> t1 a1 -> f1 (t1 a1)
        or the inferred type of
           it :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
    In the expression: traverse :: Lens (t a) a
```

Oof, it didn't like that. Oh, wait, in order to use `traverse` our type `t` has to be `Traversable`, so let's add that restriction. (Just like the "Possible fix") suggests:

```
λ :t traverse :: Traversable t => Lens (t a) a

<interactive>:1:1:
    Could not deduce (Applicative f1) arising from a use of `traverse'
    from the context (Functor f, Traversable t)
      bound by the inferred type of
               it :: (Functor f, Traversable t) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
      at Top level
    or from (Traversable t1, Functor f1)
      bound by an expression type signature:
                 (Traversable t1, Functor f1) =>
                 (a1 -> f1 a1) -> t1 a1 -> f1 (t1 a1)
      at <interactive>:1:1-41
    Possible fix:
      add (Applicative f1) to the context of
        an expression type signature:
          (Traversable t1, Functor f1) =>
          (a1 -> f1 a1) -> t1 a1 -> f1 (t1 a1)
        or the inferred type of
           it :: (Functor f, Traversable t) => (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
    In the expression: traverse :: Traversable t => Lens (t a) a
```

Ok, so the problem now is that it can't infer that `f` is `Applicative` (which is also required to use `traverse`), just that it's a `Functor` (which it gets from the definition of `Lens`).

We can't add `Applicative f` to the context though - the `f` is hidden. When we say `type Lens s a = Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s`, we're saying that the `Lens` has to work **for all** `Functor`s.

But `traverse` only works for the subset of `Functor`s that are also `Applicative`. So in this way the type of `traverse` is **more specific** than is allowed for `Lens`es.